# Issue Converting HTML Table into CSV Format

Tags: html, csv

Trouble converting a series of HTML Tables into a single CSV document.

Everything works fine until I get to a multi-line  in my html.

The converter takes: `<td> Restarted the following servers for maintenance:
-Car Care: CarCareServer -DWA: DWAHost, Server-1, Terminal -Homemasters: Homemasters, SRV0 -Monolith: Monolith, Server </td>`

And converts it into: 5 new CSV cells (one for each line). But, what I need is for all this text to be funneled into one, single, CSV cell.

Please help!

Here's my converter.

```
$('#CSVFiltDownBtn').click(function() {
  var titles = [];
  var data = [];

  /*
   * Get the table headers, this will be CSV headers
   * The count of headers will be CSV string separator
   */

  $('#filtered_table thead:first th').each(function() {

    titles.push($(this).text());

  });

    /*
     * Get the actual data, this will contain all the data, in 1 array
    */
    $('#filtered_table td').each(function() {
      //data.push($(this).text());

      var cellData = $(this).text(); 

      //var cleanData = escape(cellData); 
      var cleanData = cellData.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/-/g, "").replace(/<br>/g, ""); 
      data.push(cleanData);

    });

  /*
   * Convert our data to CSV string
   */
  var CSVString = prepCSVRow(titles, titles.length, '');
  CSVString = prepCSVRow(data, titles.length, CSVString);

  /*
   * Make CSV downloadable
   */
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", CSVString]);
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  downloadLink.href = url;
  downloadLink.download = "data.csv";

  /*
   * Actually download CSV
   */
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);

});
```

The tables are tricky to demonstrate because their numbers, and the numbers of columns, are dictated by the user (it's a filtered list), and I'm converting multiple resulting tables into a single CSV.

All tables have the same numbers of columns, and the same headers.

My primary issue is how to make sure these multi-lined td's are converting into a single CSV block.

Thoughts?

Comment: `:first` is not a valid pseudo-class unless used with the `@page` rule, `:first-child` is though. Of course, you have to know that it gets the first Element of that type according to the previous selectors, not the child of `th` but the `th` that is the first-child.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to make sure a table cell with multiple paragraphs of data will be compiled into a single CSV cell? It's giving each paragraph it's own cell, even after I've filtered out the <br>, commas, dashes and quotes. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the CSV parser you are using, so I made one showing you the technique, following the example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example .

```js
/* js/external.js */
//<![CDATA[
var doc, bod, I, S, Q, special, unspecial, csv; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
special = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
unspecial = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
}
csv = function(tableElement, linkElement){
  var thead_tr = Q('thead>tr', tableElement), tfoot_tr = Q('tfoot>tr', tableElement), tbody_tr = Q('tbody>tr', tableElement), s = '';
  for(var i=0,c=thead_tr,row,col,l=c.length; i<l; i++){
    row = thead_tr[i].childNodes;
    for(var n=0,a=[],q=row.length; n<q; n++){
      col = row[n];
      if(col.nodeType === 1)a.push('"'+unspecial(col.innerHTML).replace(/"/g, '""')+'"');
    }
    s += a.join(',')+'\n';
  }
  for(var i=0,c=tbody_tr,l=c.length; i<l; i++){
    row = tbody_tr[i].childNodes;
    for(var n=0,a=[],q=row.length; n<q; n++){
      col = row[n];
      if(col.nodeType === 1)a.push('"'+unspecial(col.innerHTML).replace(/"/g, '""')+'"');
    }
    s += a.join(',')+'\n';
  }
  for(var i=0,c=tfoot_tr,l=c.length; i<l; i++){
    row = tfoot_tr[i].childNodes;
    for(var n=0,a=[],q=row.length; n<q; n++){
      col = row[n];
      if(col.nodeType === 1)a.push('"'+unspecial(col.innerHTML).replace(/"/g, '""')+'"');
    }
    s += a.join(',')+'\n';
  }
  linkElement.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([s], {type:'text/csv'}));
}
csv(I('wiki_cars'), I('downloadLink'));
});
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  position:relative; background:#ccc;
}
table{
  background:#fff; border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td{
  border:1px solid #000; padding:3px 5px;
}
#link_container{
  text-align:center; margin:7px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='link_container'><a id='downloadLink' download='data.csv'>Click to Test</a></div>
  <table id='wiki_cars'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Year</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>total</th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th>17699.00</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1997</td><td>Ford</td><td>E350</td><td>ac, abs, moon</td><td>3000.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1999</td><td>Chevy</td><td>Venture &quot;Extended Edition&quot;</td><td></td><td>   4900.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1999</td><td>Chevy</td><td>Venture &quot;Extended Edition, Very Large&quot;</td><td></td><td>5000.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1996</td><td>Jeep</td><td>Grand Cherokee</td><td>&quot;MUST SELL! air, moon roof, loaded&quot;</td><td>4799.00</td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I did add a footer to that table. Hopefully this helps!

**PS**

Personally, I wouldn't use the `download` attribute, since it won't work on Safari on iOS. You can always create a CSV file on your Server. `.csv`s should attempt to download automatically if you link to them, since the Browser won't know what to do with that file type.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery's text use the native `innerText`.

Replace

```
var cellData = $(this).text();
```

With

```
var cellData = this.text();
```

See the snippet below for a quick and dirty demo of the difference:

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
console.log(div.innerText);
console.log($("div").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Some 
Text
</div>
```